# How to read OutputStreamBitWriter object in Java?

Tags: java, printing, stream

I have the following code:

```
OutputStreamBitWriter writer = new OutputStreamBitWriter(System.out);
writer.writeBit(1);
```

If I want to print the value or store it in a String, how do I do that?

Comment: How are we supposed to know what an OutputStreamBitWriter is?

Comment: Well it would be difficult if the class name where `TransMogriFooObscurator`, but `OutputStreamBitWriter` gives me a pretty good idea of what the class is (even though a listing would have been better)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
OutputStreamBitWriter writer = new OutputStreamBitWriter(out); 
writer.writeBit(1);
byte[] bytes = out.getBytes();
// Format and output the bytes.
```

Now since I suspect this is homework, I'm not going to spoon-feed you the complete solution.  But here's a hint: if you try to turn the bytes into a String, the chances are that it will contain non-printing characters.

Comment: Yes. I am trying to implement Huffman code as a part of my homework. I have been trying to print the bits to test my code. Thanks for your pointer. I don't need the entire solution, just wanted some clue.

Answer (score -1):

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
OutputStreamBitWriter writer = new OutputStreamBitWriter(out);
writer.writeBit(1);
//bla-bla
writer.flush();
System.out.println(new String(out.toByteArray()));
```

Comment: -1, This answer makes assumptions about the content of the OutputStreamBitWriter (whatever that is) that are unwarranted, namely that is represents the encoding of a valid string in the platform's default character set.

Comment: heh, downvote is pretty harsh.  I didn't find the answer any worse than the question, heh.

Comment: @TOny: Sorry about the question. I couldn't articulate it better. Thanks.

Comment: I agree, downvote is too harsh. +1 to balance that (not sure I would have upvoted it otherwise)

Comment: @seanizer: If OutputStreamBitWriter operates they way you think it does then this answer is a bug.